# MongoDB on my infrastructure on AWS OR DynamoDB package on AWS?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is it cheaper to create an infrastructure on AWS and run mongodb on it, or it is cheaper to use the package of DynamoDB of AWS which assure determinate characteristics?

Comment: This question is too subjective with too little detail to answer in a factual manner without giving a plain scenario-less answer like the one below which doesn't really give much insight for your particular use case. Honestly I am unsure if you would get a better answer than what you find on Google eve with the needed information as such I don't think this question is a good fit here.

Comment: On Google I have not found subjective comparisons on the costs based on a real experience, for this reason I am asking here!

Comment: The aren't equivalent technologies. If you use dynamoDb like you'd use MongoDb, it's likely to cost far more, because they aren't intended to be used the same way. But, the same is true if you tried to compare MongoDb to AWS RDS with PostgreSQL.

Comment: cant you just Google for the cost of dynamo db for your scenario and then Google search cost of MongoDB and compare the two? I doubt any formally written comparison does exist because at the end of the somethings you just need to actually research if you want to come to a educated and informed decision about your project otherwise your project is doomed to fail before it even begins.

Comment: As the other answers say regarding cost: it depends. But here's another perspective. We built an app in AWS using MongoDB on EC2, and it's been reliable and performed well for a couple of years now. But we are seriously looking into migrating it to DynamoDB because we would *love* to have an AWS provided storage service and no longer run MongoDB ourselves. We want to focus on our app, not things like running a database.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on your use case:

**Dynamo:** is relatively cheap if your access for read / write is not massive. Storage for it, is really cheap ($0.25 per Gb). Also you also gain the ability of scale and not have to maintain backups, replicas, etc, etc as you will do it by your own managed MongoDb.
Regarding the features, and there is where your data model applies, you have to take into consideration that the search features are not as powerful as the MongoDb ones, however, if you are imaginative, you will be able to adapt your model to it. Also, in a couple of weeks a new feature (Global Secondary Indexes), will be added to Dynamo, so it would be possible to search by other fields that are not in the Key and the Range key, and without projections (something that now is available with the Secondary Indexes.

**MongoDb:** Depends: you have to think that you will have to mantain the infraestructure (server), backups, etc, etc. Also the cheap instances of AWS does not have a high amount of memory or SSD, so you will have to go to bigger instances that have a high price per month. there is also another possibility, use Mongo provided by some SaaS like MongoHq, etc, but again, that will be expensive.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you know if DynamoDB have geospatial index and query as mongodb?

Comment: Not directly, but you can use geohashes (and use the beginWith over the range key). Even AWS has published a library using this approach (that you can use directly or get the ideas of how to implement it in your code):
http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/09/new-geo-library-for-dynamodb-.html

Comment: Another question.. Do you know where I can find some benchmarks about mongodb on ec2? For example: if I use a replica set of 3 istances and no sharing, how many reads or write per seconds I can do? Otherwise. If I use sharding, how many rw/seconds? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Michele, I don't have this info... however internet is full of benchmarks about Mongo, with different configurations. Also, never, never trust 100% in benchmarks: I suggest to you to try it by yourself. Install your app, instrumentalize your code with something like NewRelic, and get your conclusions..